# Convert Sql query into vb script

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, vbscript

I have the below SQL query. I wanted to execute the same query in [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript), but am not able convert it and not getting proper result. Can I get the correct convert format?

```
SELECT distinct CASE 
WHEN enty_typ_cd = 'acct' THEN 'Account : '
WHEN enty_typ_cd = 'pfolio' THEN 'Portfolo : '
END +
a.mstr_shrt_nm_id as [ ]
FROM RCMglbl..nav_nt a, RCMglbl..enty_mstr b
WHERE a.enty_id = b.id AND office = 'sf'
AND mnth_end_dt <> (select lst_mo_end_dt from RCMglbl..proc_dt)
AND mnth_end_dt is not NULL
```

Comment: What code do you have so far for your script? What error do you get?

Comment: The SQL query itself is not going to change, just because you run it from a different environmen (VBScript in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure what you mean by converting the string to an `VBscript`... Like the Ansgar Wiechers said, the string remains the same, the environment changes 
*anyway...* 
Place this code in `notepad.exe` 
edit the [connection string](http://connectionstrings.com/) to suit your server
save file with `.vbs` extension
locate it and run it!

```
Const adUseClient = 3
Dim cn
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

dim sql
sql = "SELECT distinct CASE " & _
        "WHEN enty_typ_cd = 'acct' THEN 'Account : ' " & _ 
        "WHEN enty_typ_cd = 'pfolio' THEN 'Portfolo : ' " & _ 
        "END + a.mstr_shrt_nm_id as [ ] " & _
        "FROM RCMglbl..nav_nt a, RCMglbl..enty_mstr b " & _ 
        "WHERE a.enty_id = b.id AND office = 'sf' " & _ 
        "AND mnth_end_dt <> (select lst_mo_end_dt from RCMglbl..proc_dt) " & _
        "AND mnth_end_dt is not NULL"
with cn 
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=SERVER_NAME; Database=DATABASE_NAME; UID=USER_ID_NAME; PWD=PASSWORD"
    .CommandTimeout = 0
    .Execute(sql)
end with

cn.close
set cn = Nothing
```

Once you get that working, youve gotta think about the result your getting from your query... therefore, i advise on reading more about [SELECT STATEMENT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp) and possibly a [RECORDSET](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_ref_recordset.asp)

Comment: VBScript doesn't know a constant `adUseClient`, so it must be defined as `Const adUseClient = 3`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers yes! i totally forgot ( been writing macros in vba all morning ), nice catch!